# Chrome Extensions - Grabbing url data in the background

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

Using a Chrome Extension Background Script, is it possible to carry out a request which grabs the response from a requested URL which the Extension is allowed to access? I keep getting denied (CORBS or cross-browser cookie errors). If so, how does one go about doing this? My extension's background.js is being seen as an outsider.

Comment: It should just work assuming this is an indeed a background script, not just a script that's named background.js but loaded as a content script. Anyway, the question is unanswerable without [MCVE](/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0):

I believe my issue was that I had not included the url in manifist.json permissions.

Comment: This is why you need to include [MCVE](/help/mcve) in the question: programming isn't based on belief but on a fact.